# ARIMAX and auto.arima for multivariate time series forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, multivariate-regression

I'm trying to do multivariate time series forecasting using the `forecast` package in R. The data set contains one dependent and independent variable.
From the cross-correlation the 0 day lag of the independent variable seems to have better correlation with dependent variable.

But I need some clarification on which function I should use - `auto.arima` with `xreg` or `arimax`.

1. While using `auto.arima` to predict the dependent variable by using independent Variable as the `xreg` parameter in the `auto.arima` function,Do we need to have `xreg` values in place already for the forecast periods?
2. Or Can we use `arimax` to predict the dependent variable along with a covariate even if there are no values available for the covariate on the forecast periods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the future values of the covariate to make ARIMAX (or perhaps regression with ARIMA errors – see [The ARIMAX model muddle](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) by Rob J Hyndman) feasible. If you do not have these values, you may need to forecast them. This could be done separately or jointly with the dependent variable. In the latter case, a multivariate time series model such as VAR (vector autoregression) could be used.

Comment: Thank you Richard for the answer.. So you are suggesting I should get the future values of the independent variable using ARIMA or VAR and then use that again as a regressor to the ARIMAX or auto.arima(with xreg) to predict the dependent variable?

Comment: @ArvindMenon, no, it is either or. Either use ARIMA for the exogenous regressor followed by `auto.arima` (for the dependent variable) with `xreg` (the forecasts of the regressor). Or use VAR for forecasting both variables simultaneously (no need for `auto.arima` with `xreg` then).

Comment: Thank you Richard. I go with the first approach since the co-relation is not both ways i would restrain myself from using VAR.

Comment: @ArvindMenon, you are welcome. Good luck!